# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta sql de una tabla que tiene dos foreign key de una tabla?

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas rutas y municipios de la siguiente manera:

**Rutas**:
id,
id_municipio_salida,
id_municipio_llegada,
valor

**Municipios**:
id,
nombre

Cómo hacer para que la consulta SQL me genere de esta manera:

[image: Rutas]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende tu consulta.. cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Como hacen para poner un link en los comentarios ? o donde puedo ver como hacerlo ? Gracias

Comment: @MateoGuio mira aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting en el titulo "enlaces". Yo uso el primero. No creo que funcionen los otros dos en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dices, tienes llaves foráneas a la misma tabla dos veces. Entonces lo que puedes hacer es un `JOIN` a la misma tabla, dos veces!

```
SELECT rutas.ruta_id, 
       rutas.id_municipio_salida, 
       rutas.id_municipio_llegada, 
       rutas.valor, 
       ms.nombre, 
       ml.nombre
FROM rutas
JOIN municipios ms on id_municipio_salida = ms.municipio_id
JOIN municipios ml on id_municipio_llegada = ml.municipio_id
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfecto.